# JUnit5 react to @Before* methods failure

Tags: junit, junit5

Is there any hook in Junit5 that reacts to fails in @Before* methods?

I use a @BeforeAll method to init environment for my tests. But this initialization may sometimes fail. I want to dump the environment, to find out whats wrong, but I need to do it before @After* methods are called, which will clear the environment and destroy all info.

We're talking about dozens of these @BeforeAll methods across the test suite, so doing it manually inside each method is not an option.

I've already tried these, but no luck:

- `TestWatcher` does not work for this, since it only fires if an actual test is executed.
- `TestExecutionListener.executionFinished` looks promising, but it fires after all the @After methods, which is too late for me.
- I even tried to do it inside the @AfterAll cleanup methods, before the actual cleanup. But found no way to detect which tests were executed or if anything failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "fails in @Before* methods" you mean exceptions? If that is the case, you could leverage the [extension model](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) as follows:

```java
@ExtendWith(DumpEnvOnFailureExtension.class)
class SomeTest {

    static class DumpEnvOnFailureExtension implements LifecycleMethodExecutionExceptionHandler {

        @Override
        public void handleBeforeAllMethodExecutionException(final ExtensionContext context, final Throwable ex)
                throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("handleBeforeAllMethodExecutionException()");
            // dump env
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpOnce() {
        System.out.println("setUpOnce()");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        // some test
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownOnce() {
        System.out.println("tearDownOnce()");
    }

}
```

The log will be:

```
setUpOnce()
handleBeforeAllMethodExecutionException()
tearDownOnce()
```

That is, the extension is notified if the `@BeforeAll` method fails with an exception. (Note that this is just an MWE, for the actual implementation you would extract `DumpEnvOnFailureExtension` and use it wherever needed.)

For further information, check out section ["Exception Handling"](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-exception-handling) in the user guide.

Comment: Yes by fails I mean Exception is thrown. Thanks, this seems to solve my problem.